# DemandTools security related to SalesForce

Tags: data-loader, community

To any DemandTools users out there - we are trying to automate our interfaces to and from SalesForce using DemandTools product.  When the scheduled task tries to execute, it is failing because it says the user account needs to be a System Administrator.  When we execute the process manually, we do not get that same restriction.  What are others doing to address this issue?  Our concern is providing a System Administrator password that could be used to upload or extract things that should not be.

Update 11/6/13: The answer originally provided is not a solution.  We sent a request to support@crmfusion.com and received the following reply - 'Due to the popularity of our Not for Profit software grant program (now more than 4000 NFP Organizations), unfortunately as of January 1, 2013, we are no longer able to provide direct technical support of any type to our Not for Profit granted friends.' This is from a Sr Customer Success Manager. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Per [this help article](http://na13.salesforce.com/_ui/selfservice/pkb/PublicKnowledgeSolution/d?orgId=00D300000000RBY&id=50130000000W8T4&ps=1&pPv=1) the requirement is that the profile have "view setup & configuration" and "modify all data". Obviously, still a very permissive profile. But would that meet your need? 
Alternatively, what are you doing with DemandTools on an automated basis? If it's data extraction and/or insertion without any DT-specific functions, you might be better served using a lighter-weight tool like the Apex Data Loader or Jitterbit Data Loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all NFP users out there, this is what we found out about support -

NOTE: NFP users do not receive technical support as part of the NFP software grant. In addition to the help documentation and Public Knowledge Base, we have developed a Tech Forum, http://support.crmfusion.com, to allow NFP users a place to exchange questions, ideas and receive community support from peers.

This is a footnote that was on a followup note I received from DemandTools when I attended training.

As for our issue with security, the comment from Thomas Taylor provided a helpful link to an article that talked about the security settings needed to be considered an administrator.  We are also in the process of evaluating Jitterbit, so we have not tried this solution yet.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the multitude of administrator features that DemandTools offers, use of their product out-of-the-box only works as a user with a System Administrator profile, per their documentation. You can enable access for users with other profiles by request by contacting support@crmfusion.com

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  This is what we were looking for.